# Getting auto-incremented int from just created row?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting a row into a table, like so:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO post(name,message,date)VALUES('$name','$message','$date')");
```

The table 'post' has an auto-incremented int column, called 'postInt'. How do easily get this int of the just-created row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

> mysql_insert_id — Get the ID generated
>   in the last query

Just make sure to call this method immediately after you run the `INSERT` query because this method will act on the last performed query.

Answer (score 4):

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 3):

This is mysql version.

```
select last_insert_id()
```

Answer (score 2):

printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());